# How to change a color using Jquery AJAX click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i have one question about click change color think.

I am trying to make a like unlike button like facebook.

So i created this function:

```
//Like and Unlike
$('.commentlike').click(function() 
{
  var ID = $(this).attr("id");
  var sid=ID.split("clike"); 
  var New_ID=sid[1];
  var REL = $(this).attr("rel");
  var URL=$.base_url+'like_post.php';
  var dataString = 'com_id=' + New_ID +'&rel='+ REL;
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
      if(REL=='Like')
      {
        $('#'+ID).html('Unlike').attr('rel', 'Unlike').attr('title', 'Unlike');
        $("#count_container"+New_ID).fadeIn('slow');
        $(".comment_count"+New_ID).html(html);
      }
      else
      {
        $('#'+ID).attr('rel', 'Like').attr('title', 'Like').html('Like');
        if(html>0)
        {
          $(".comment_count"+New_ID).html(html);    
        }
        else
        {
          $("#count_container"+New_ID).fadeOut('slow'); 
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

and this is button
Like button:

```
<div class="icon-begen-yorum commentlike icon-thumbs-up" id="clike'.$com_id.'" title="Like" rel="Like"></div>
```

Unlike button:

```
<div class="icon-begenilen-yorum commentlike icon-thumbs-up" id="clike'.$com_id.'"title="Unlike" rel="Unlike"></div>
```

so this is like and unlike button CSS:

Like button color:

```
.icon-begen-yorum{margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding-top:7px;height:23px;width:23px;color:#919bb2 !important;overflow:hidden;float:left;font-size:15px;cursor:pointer;}
```

Unlike button color:

```
.icon-begenilen-yorum{margin:0;margin-right:5px;padding-top:7px;height:23px;width:23px;color:#d95e40 !important;overflow:hidden;float:left;font-size:15px;cursor:pointer;}
```

Now what i want to do here. When user click Like button then automatically change color to Unlike color. Then if user again click Unlike button then button color automatically change like button color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by creating an "active" class and using `toggleClass()` to switch back and forth on `.click()`. Just be sure your toggle class is being declared under your button class or else it won't override the changes:

**JS**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("active");    
});
```

**CSS**

```
.btn{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer

}

.active{
    background: green;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgfj9xnm/)

Comment: Dear friend can you help me just one question ?